# Kafka connect Debezium Mongo source connector cannot connect to the MongoDb instance

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

The following commands are used to setup Zookeeper, Kafka, Schema-registry, Kafka-connect and MongoDb in Docker. The Kakfa-connect cluster doesn't seem to connect to the MongoDb and it's continuously showing `Connection refused`. All the containers are deployed in a docker network called confluent.

```
# create confluent network \ 
docker network create confluent && \

# create Zookeeper \ 
docker run -d \
    --name=zookeeper \
    --net=confluent \
    -p 2181:2181 \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 \
    confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.0 && \ 

# create kafka \ 
docker run -d \
    --name=kafka \
    --net=confluent \
    -p 9092:9092 \
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181 \
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092 \
    -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
    confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0 && \

# create schema-registry \ 
docker run -d \
  --name=schema-registry \
  --net=confluent \
  -p 8081:8081 \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181 \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
  -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081 \
  confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.0 && \

# create kafka-connect \ 
docker run -d \
  --name=kafka-connect \
  --net=confluent \
  -p 8083:8083 \
  -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 \
  -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083 \
  -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-config" \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-offsets" \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quickstart-status" \
  -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
  -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="kafka-connect" \
  -e CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
  -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java \
  -e CONNECT_REST_HOST_NAME="kafka-connect" \
  -v /tmp/quickstart/file:/tmp/quickstart \
  confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0 && \

# create mongo \ 
docker pull mongo && \
docker run -d --name=mongodb --net=confluent  -v $(pwd)/data/db:/data/db -p 27017:27017 -d mongo  --replSet debezium && \
docker exec -it mongodb mongosh --eval 'rs.initiate({_id: "debezium", members:[{_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"}]})'
```

I'm using the following commands to setup the Kafka Debezium MongoDb connector

```
docker exec -it kafka-connect bash
confluent-hub install debezium/debezium-connector-mongodb:0.9.4
docker restart kafka-connect
```

And lastly I'm using the following in mongosh to create the user for Debezium

```
use admin
db.createUser(
 {
  user: "debezium",
  pwd: "dbz",
  roles: ["dbOwner"]
 })
```

Now I'm trying to setup the MongoDb Debezium Kafka connector with the following json file

```
{
    "name": "inventory-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "mongodb.hosts": "debezium/127.0.0.1:27017",
        "mongodb.name": "dbserver1",
        "mongodb.user": "debezium",
        "mongodb.password": "dbz"
    }
}

curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @register-mongodb.json
```

Now when I trigger the above curl command, here is the error messaging I see in the Kafka-connect docker container

```
[2023-04-29 12:58:26,106] DEBUG Getting plugin class loader for connector: 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
    connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
    connector.class = io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector
[2023-04-29 12:58:26,132] DEBUG Getting plugin class loader for connector: 'io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
[2023-04-29 12:58:26,144] INFO Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out (org.mongodb.driver.cluster)

[2023-04-29 12:58:43,303] DEBUG Closing connection connectionId{localValue:36} (org.mongodb.driver.connection)
[2023-04-29 12:58:43,304] DEBUG Updating cluster description to  
{type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception=
{com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, 
caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}] 
(org.mongodb.driver.cluster)
```

It seems that the Kafka-connect cluster cannot connect to the MongoDb. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You will probably need the containers on the same network. You can add mongo in the docker compose and attach them all on the same network

Comment: They're all in the same network called confluent

Comment: Why not use Docker Compose to simply all that? And why not use latest versions of those images?

Answer (score 0):

```
debezium/127.0.0.1:27017
```

With a slash, that's not a valid hostname, and none of your containers are named debezium. You want to connect to the Mongo container.

You set `--name=mongodv`. Use that rather than trying to make Connect container start a Mongo client with an address pointed at itself, as the error is saying.

Comment: So if you check the Mongo debezium documentation on confluent - https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/debezium-mongodb-source/current/mongodb_source_connector_config.html#mongodb-source-connector-config - we need to provide a replica set and in my case the name of the replica set is "debezium". Also I tried "debezium/mongodb:27017" and "mongodb:27017" and both did not work and gave me the exact same error above.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the official Debezium documentation rather than Confluent, but in your Mongo initialize statement, can you also use `host: "mongodb:27017"`?